# d3 add zoom functionality to d3.xml loaded element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am dynamically loading an svg image using `d3.xml`. I then want to attach zoom functionality to this svg by using `d3.behavior.zoom()`.

Can anyone explain how to link `d3.behavior.zoom()` with the loaded svg? I cannot find anything online.

See current code below:

**JS**

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

d3.xml("map.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
   if (error) throw error;
   var svg = d3.select(xml.documentElement)
   .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
       svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
   }))
   .append("g");
});
```

Comment: Please post the function *zoom()*

Comment: @MarioSantini i believe this is included in the d3 library

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

Comment: @MarioSantini i am able to get this working, but the reason this is different is that I am loading the svg element using d3.xml where i can't get the zoom working

Comment: You have just loaded your SVGs content. You need to import it into the DOM to be able to listen for events on this document. For an in-depth explanation about how this is done please have a look at [*"How do I dynamically insert an SVG image into HTML?"*](/q/7981100).

Comment: @altocumulus i am able to display it. but just when i try and `append 'g'` it doesn't work properly

Comment: @phantom Please post the entire code necessary to reproduce this, i.e. set up a {mcve]. The code you provide will definitely not display the loaded SVG and will not allow for appending further elements or attaching event handlers the way you are trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have two questions here:

**Problem 1:** Loading and appending the external SVG

In your code, you're not appending the SVG to the document. So, the first step is actually appending the SVG:

```
d3.xml("externalSVG.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
    if (error) throw error;
    document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
    //rest of the code here
});
```

**Problem 2**: Adding the zoom

The code you provide is adding the zoom to the `<g>` element, not to the entire SVG. Thus, it will not work zooming the external SVG. To do that, you can write something like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.selectAll("*")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" 
        + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
}))
```

Check the demo:

```js
d3.xml("https://boxy-svg.com/images/logos/boxy-svg.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
  if (error) throw error;
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
  var svg = d3.select("svg")
   .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
       svg.selectAll("*").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
   }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```